# How can I set up login using Fancybox?

Tags: jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am trying to open a control panel in [FANCYBOX](http://fancybox.net/).

I have a form in my page which its action and field names are same as another website and once user submit it they will redirect to their control panel in that website in a new window.

What I want is to open it in fancybox. I do not want to user leave my page, I just want them to access to that panel inside my website.

And also I want to all links of the opened frame target be `_parent`. I mean if they go to different parts of their panel it shows in the same fancybox not open a new window.

Comment: Is your shift key broken? The letter I is always capitalized when it stands alone. So is the first letter of every new sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look at `iframe` i.e. Add `class='iframe'` to a link check it on [this page](http://fancybox.net/howto).

Comment: How can i call fancybox by a submit button. i need to post information to login into panel